# Why do I see TypeScript in Vue.js source code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I went through the vue.js source code just to have a look, and I saw some strange code, which I learnt was TypeScript syntax after some research. My problem is, this syntax is in a ".js" file, which I don't understand because I know TypeScript files (.ts) should compile to pure JS. So why do I still see the type annotation in the function parameter in a .js file?

```
function hasAncestorData (node: VNode) {
  const parentNode = node.parent
  return isDef(parentNode) && (isDef(parentNode.data) || hasAncestorData(parentNode))
}
```

Comment: It would help us answer your question if you showed us **where** you found this (what file, where that file was, what line).

Comment: As Mateus points out, it's Flow, not TypeScript (but a JavaScript engine would still complain about those type annotations). Filename extensions are largely a matter of convention. There's nothing other than convention preventing you putting TypeScript, or JavaScript w/Flow, in a file with the extension `.js` (provided, again, you don't try to execute it directly in an environment that expects the contents to be pure JavaScript).

Answer (score 8):

This is actually a [Flow](https://flow.org) code. You can see the `/* @flow */` comment at the beginning of [some files](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/42fdf3f8378e5dc379808a4fa67b39c4a74ae191/src/server/render.js#L1) that enables the tool's type checking. It's a bit similar to TypeScript, but those are not the same things.

A quick look through the `src` folder of [the Vue.js github repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/dev/src/core/vdom) shows that they do indeed use `.js` for their JavaScript w/Flow code, for instance in [`src/core/vdom/create-component.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/core/vdom/create-component.js):

> ```
> const componentVNodeHooks = {
>   init (vnode: VNodeWithData, hydrating: boolean): ?boolean {
> ```

But if we look in the `dist` folder, we can see that those Flow type annotations have been removed for distribution. For instance, here's the above in [`dist/vue.js`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/dist/vue.js#L3110) (that line number will rot over time):

> ```
> var componentVNodeHooks = {
>   init: function init (vnode, hydrating) {
> ```

Comment: Me: ***"Doh!"***